# Memory Release of a const pointer from either of two different callbacks in asynchronous code

Tags: c++, pointers, asynchronous, free

I have a scenario in my C++ code where i have some stream of data (const char*) and i want to do following with the stream

1. Serialize stream using serialize callback
2. send serialized stream to some external server asynchronously.
3. Execute done Callback in case of success or failure

Now I have to release memory occupied by a raw stream (non serialized). Currently I am deleting it in serialize callback. The Problem is: there are some negative cases where Serialize Callback won't trigger. And as I was releasing memory in serialize callback I have a memory leak. But my done callback will be called anyway. I don't want to move deletion part two done callback because I am expecting lots of data and I don't want to keep anything for more than necessary in memory. I am thinking of doing the following:

1. pass raw stream to both serializeCb and doneCb.
2. In SerialiizeCb delete raw stream and make the it NULL.
3. In doneCb check if raw stream is NULL, if not delete it.

Does it look clean ? or i can do something better.

```
void serializeCb(const char * rawStream)
{
    // some other code.
    delete rawStream;
    rawStream = NULL;
}

void doneCb(const char* rawStream)
{
    if(rawStream != NULL){
        delete rawStream;
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks horrible 1) there are no const pointers here 2) passing raw pointers around does not imply ownership transfer 3) delete rawStream most likely will be UB because it points to array of objects 4) nullptr should be preferred to NULL 5) smart pointers should be preferred to manual memory cleanup

Comment: Not much information here. Better if you can provide an MCVE. Fundamental problem as I see it is that you don't seem to know which part of the code "owns" the lifetime of the buffer. Cleanup should be done in the callback that will be deterministically called. (i.e. you can prove it will be called). That looks like `doneCB` to me.

Comment: @RichardHodges Actually full code is too big and that won't be possible to copy here. But you understood the problem. i am not sure which part of the code will delete the code, but there are following things which are certain.  
1. Either SerializeCb or doneCb will free memory.
2. First SerializeCb will be called , then doneCb.
3. It's not guaranteed that SerializeCb will be called but call of doneCb is guaranteed.
Note: I had freeing logic in doneCb so far. but execution of doneCb may take upto 10 minute in worst case and data is coming so fast that i might end in out of memory situation.

Comment: @VTT 1) My bad, what i meant is const char pointer.
2) What should i do then ?
3) I don't understand why it will point to array of objects.
5) I don't have luxury of smart pointer as  i have to call some API which takes char * only.